# Nodejs to accept command line argument that contain ( or )

Tags: node.js, bash, command-line-arguments

I have made a node application that take any text as argument and my application takes that text and stores that in the database.

When I am giving any text that contain the ( or ) in it then I get an error from bash as

-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

How can i accept arguments which contain ( or ) in the text

Comment: I think it would help if you showed us the complete commands and relevant source code.

Answer (score 2):

Quote the argument(s), preferably using single quotes:

```
node app.js 'foo ( or ) bar'
```

Comment: that worked but is there any way without enclosing my text with '

Comment: You can also use double quotes, but you'd have to make sure that there aren't any other shell-specials (like `$`) in the string you pass.